# What does the letter "e" mean in the declaration of a double? - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, double

In some code I found this statement:

```
constraints: const BoxConstraints(
  maxWidth: 10e2,
),
```

what does the letter "e" mean?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation

Comment: I think it will be 1000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exponent of 10. Similar to calculators. 10e2 would be equal to:
10 * 10 ^ 2 = 1000.